# How to organise json translations with nested folders in next-i18next?

Tags: next.js, i18next

Hi all I am using Next 12.0 and "next-i18next": "8.6.0",

My next-i18next.config.js looks like below

```
const path = require('path');

/**
 * When converting this to typescript can import locales from src/c/constants/locales.ts instead of repeating here
 */

module.exports = {
    localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales'),
    i18n: {
        localeDetection: false,
        defaultLocale: 'de',
        locales: ['de', 'en'],
        fallbackLng: [],
    },
};
```

putting files like `public/static/locales/en/home.json` and importing it in serversideprops like

```
export async function getStaticProps({
    locale,
}: GetStaticPropsContext): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<ServerProps>> {
    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['home']),
        },
    };
}
```

works great. I can use these on the client side with the `useTranslations('home)` hook without issue.

**My issue is that I want to organise the translations better by using nested folders.**

I want to have a folder `blocks` under `public/static/locales/en` and inside have for example

- `public/static/locales/en/blocks/a.json`
- `public/static/locales/en/blocks/b.json`
- etc more base blocks

I have a blocks system that build pages dynamically, therefore don't want to include translations that are not needed for no reason.

I noticed that trying to import a namespace like "blocks/a" fails and this is blocking me from achieving the desired result.
If I keep the file in the root of the locale it works like `public/static/locales/a.json` then I can refer to namespace `a`

Any help here on how I can do this ?